# check if 10 objects are present in aws s3 bucket using single API call

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am using javascript AWS SDK

Constraints:

1. I don't want content for those 10 objects, just want to know if those are present or not
2. I want to make a single API to AWS S3

Comment: You can use ListObjectsV2 if those objects share a prefix and there aren't many other objects with the same prefix, or HeadObject to check for one object at a time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, the objects have unique names, they didn't have any common prefix. What to do in that case?
Using HeadObject lead to make several calls to S3 because using HeadObject we can get only single object metadata

Comment: Yes, if the objects share no common prefix, then you'll need to make several calls to HeadObject to see if they exist.